# PDO: FetchAll returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep receiving an empty array when i try to execute the following code:

```
$this->DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Author = :username AND Timestamp < :timestamp ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT :limit;');
$this->DB->bind(':username', $username);
$this->DB->bind(':timestamp', $start);
$this->DB->bind(':limit', $numberOfResults, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$data = $this->DB->execute();
```

These are the `bind`, `prepare` and `execute` functions:

```
public function bind($placeholder, $value, $type = \PDO::PARAM_STR) {

    $this->preparedQuery->bindParam($placeholder, $value, $type);
}

public function prepare($query) {

    if(!$this->preparedQuery = $this->connection->prepare($query)) {

        print_r($this->connection->errorInfo());
        die();
    }
}

public function execute() {

    if(!$this->preparedQuery->execute()) {

        print_r($this->preparedQuery->errorInfo());
        die();
    }

    return $this->preparedQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I have also tryed to manually execute the query in **MySQL Workbench** and it's perfectly working.

**Edit:**

This is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Author = "TestUser" AND Timestamp < "9000-12-31 23:59:59" ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

**Edit 2:**

I just found out that if I remove the condition about the `Timestamp` the query returns values correctly.

Comment: Did you try this query with raw PDO, without all that useless homebrewed stuff?

Comment: Nope, but other queries are perfectly working. And by the way, why is that useless? I've found it pretty useful until now, expecially when i got errors.

Comment: what is the value of your limit - maybe this is your problem

Comment: it is useless because it duplicates raw PDO for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally come to a solution.

Thanks to **Edit 2** i realized that, just like 90% of my errors, this was a stupid one.

The `$start` variable was actually empty even if in the code was correctly initialized in the function declaration. This was causing to have an empty string to be passed to the `bindParam()` function.

Personal comment: *I am an idiot*.

Comment: to add to this: PDO is able to report errors by itself. And can do it WAY better than you do in your surrogate methods. Just set it in exception mode.